# How to show the sum of amount_sold for product 5 for each day of the week for months april, may and june in year 2000?

Tags: oracle

I need to execute a query to show the name of the month in which product 5 was sold, the product name, the monday to sunday for each day how much was sold (ex. for Monday were sold 30, 10, 60 and I've to sum it and show it under column Monday as 100)I expect to have a functional  table with all the data correctly shown.I've only worked on oracle for this task. Everything I have done except the SUM of the amount_sold for each day & then I've to aggregate so I have 3 rows for each month April, May and June with all data.

```
select t.calendar_month_name as "SALES_MONTH", 
upper(concat(substr(p.prod_name,1,instr(p.prod_name,' ')-2),' &'))
||''|| concat(substr(p.prod_name,-1,instr(' ',p.prod_name)-1), '')
||''|| concat(substr(p.prod_name,instr(p.prod_name, ' ')), '')
||'('|| p.prod_id ||')'|| '' PRODUCT_NAME, t.calendar_month_number, t.time_id, t.DAY_NUMBER_IN_WEEK,
s.amount_sold, count(distinct t.day_number_in_week), 
sum(case when t.day_number_in_week = 1 then s.amount_sold else 0 end) as MONDAY

from products p
join sales s on p.prod_id = s.prod_id
join times t on t.time_id = s.TIME_ID
where
p.prod_id = 5 and 
s.time_id = t.time_id and
t.calendar_year = 2000 and
t.calendar_quarter_number = 2 and
s.amount_sold > 0 
group by t.calendar_month_name, upper(concat(substr(p.prod_name,1,instr(p.prod_name,' ')-2),' &'))
||''|| concat(substr(p.prod_name,-1,instr(' ',p.prod_name)-1), '')
||''|| concat(substr(p.prod_name,instr(p.prod_name, ' ')), '')
||'('|| p.prod_id ||')'|| '',t.calendar_month_number, t.time_id, t.DAY_NUMBER_IN_WEEK,
s.amount_sold
order by t.calendar_month_number, t.time_id, t.day_number_in_week;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use group by and rollup